# How to get rid of "Cases and controls must be numeric or ordered." In pROC package?

Tags: r, proc, auc

I am attempting to adapt code that I've used to generate ROC curves in the past for very similar data but a new error message is generated that doesn't happen with the other dataset even though they are formatted identically.
Here is the code:

```
control<-subset(thesis_rep_dat,view==0 & nso==0) 
gvnso<-subset(thesis_rep_dat,view==0 & nso==1) 
pvcont<-subset(thesis_rep_dat,view==1 & nso==0)
pvnso<-subset(thesis_rep_dat,view==1 & nso==1)

##Now let's create ROCs for each condition
rocobj1<roc(controls=control$conf3[control$ta_tp==0],cases=control$conf3[control$ta_tp==1],
levels=c(0,1),direction="<",partial.auc=FALSE)
rocobj2 <-roc(controls=gvnso$conf3[gvnso$ta_tp==0],cases=gvnso$conf3[gvnso$ta_tp==1],
levels=c(0,1),direction="<",partial.auc=FALSE)
rocobj3 <- roc(controls=pvcont$conf3[pvcont$ta_tp==0],cases=pvcont$conf3[pvcont$ta_tp==1],
levels=c(0,1),direction="<",partial.auc=FALSE)
rocobj4 <- roc(controls=pvnso$conf3[pvnso$ta_tp==0],cases=pvnso$conf3[pvnso$ta_tp==1],
levels=c(0,1),direction="<",partial.auc=FALSE)
```

R returns the following error message:

> Error in roc.default(controls =control$conf3[gvnso$ta_tp == 0], cases = control$conf3[gvnso$ta_tp ==  : Cases and controls must be numeric or ordered.

I've tried to use the argument:

```
         control$ta_tp<-as.numeric(control$ta_tp)
```

preceding the construction of the ROC objects but it returns the same error.

I'm sorry for my naivete with this!

Comment: It is difficult to comment without looking at the data. However, `control$ta_tp<-as.numeric(control$ta_tp)` is often a risky approach. Because if `ta_tp` is a factor variable, you may get weird results even if it produces something.

Comment: Thanks for this. The data is in an excel spreadsheet. The column in question is represented as a number but indicates group assignment, either 0 (controls) or 1 (cases). It should be a no-brainer for pROC to understand this variable.